# Can not boot windows after installing ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu in a computer with Windows preinstalled but when doing it I didn't disable fast startup and now can't boot Windows.

I am using `GRUB` to boot. In the `GRUB` menu I can see Windows, but when I choose it - the screen becomes black and nothing happens.

The thing is that I was able to boot Windows at first but I do not know why, I can not boot it know. Does anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Are you using `GRUB` or `EFI` to boot? Do you have access to BIOS?

Comment: I use GRUB. Yes I can access the BIOS

Comment: GRUB should allow you to choose OS at the startup. Can you do that? Do you see windows?

Comment: Yes, I see Windows, but if i choose to boot it, a black screen appears and it doesn't load.

Comment: Have you tried boor repair?