# windows not bootable after linux mint installation

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

After installing Mint 21.2 next to windows I could not boot on windows

my situation is different from
[Can not boot windows after installing ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271777/can-not-boot-windows-after-installing-ubuntu)

as windows is not even present in the GRUB

ps: the GRUB was not showing, but I fixed by following https://livingthelinuxlifestyle.wordpress.com/2020/10/21/show-the-grub-boot-menu-in-linux-mint-at-startup/

Answer (score -1):

After 15 minutes of cold sweat (as this was not my laptop) I found this dirty solution:

I simply edited the NTFS partition containing the windows boot (*), setting  it as 'bootable'
(e.g. with `disks` app ->  'edit partition' -> select '**bootable**' -> 'change')

In the boot-loader** I had already 2 options (apart from CD/DVD).
The other option (non-Ubuntu, which is simply called with the SSD name)  now is correctly launching Windows

(*) this assumes that you did not delete anything while installing linux (mint), namely:
resize windows partition -> create ext4  + EFI partitions

** (press `F2` immediately after machine restart)

Comment: Did you create a second ESP - efi system partition. There should only be one per drive and both Windows and Linux share that one ESP. If you have two ESP, you later may have issues. You can change fstab to correct ESP and totally reinstall grub to update UEFI entry & added UEFI boot files into /EFI/ubuntu on correct ESP.

Comment: ok I see - I created  a new one, as I was afraid to destroy windows boot files.
So, you mean, Ubuntu and win should share the same EFI partition...so, Ubuntu boot files should be copied into the one  of windows ?

Comment: You can backup ESP as boot files are just files. But UEFI uses the GUID/partUUID to know which ESP to use. And fstab has the mount of the ESP to know where on a major update or reinstall of grub to put files. For boot files often easier to just totally reinstall boot loaded using Ubuntu live installer or Windows repair/recovery drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294353/understanding-my-boot-efi-tree/1294463#1294463  Also look at `cat /etc/fstab` to see UUID of ESP.  If you change fstab with new ESP & reinstall grub `sudo grub-install` (uses all default) to reset everything.